# On ubuntu while using JavaScript, what command should I enter to delete my files having a common name in them? You can also use wildcards to help me

Tags: command-line, delete, filename, javascript, wildcards

For example, I have four files with the names as "one-beta.txt" , "one-alpha.txt" , "two-beta.txt" , "three-gamma.txt". Now I am supposed to delete my files with the name "beta" in them.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused with the question.

Do you have files in a folder and would like to run a command that deletes all the files in the folder with the name beta?

if so, "rm" is your friend. I am not a big linux or ubuntu person, however, rm have been my friend for a while.

rm beta*.txt

will delete all your files that has beta and ends with txt.

If you are developing a javascript program to delete a file, then it may be a little more involve. I don't currently have that skill but you have to use javascript filereader, and check if files exist, find the files you want to delete then delete them.  check out https://javascript.info/file.  You can also find additional training on javascript at https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp.

Comment: Brother I have to delete files that are in more than one directories with the common name having beta in them just like I described in the body of my question that I have four files having names "one-beta.txt" , "one-alpha.txt" , "two-beta.txt" , "three-gamma.txt". Now what command should I enter so that I would be able to delete all files in all the subdirectories of my pwd. Is there any such command?

Comment: the file names are different so you have to start by running the following command one at a time as root. and be careful.   First try the following: **"find . -name *-beta*.txt -type f"**  ( "-type f",  will list all the files) so you can change the -name to reflect  *-alpha, *.gamma* etc,  once you are satisfy,  then add -delete to delete the files you find.  finally you can type **"find /folderpath/*-alpha*.txt -type f -delete"** or  **"find . -name *-beta.txt -type f -delete"**  ( using path to the folder, speeds up the search)  good luck "with  great power, comes great responsibilities"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have successfully done my task with the following code "find /path/to/your/directory -type f -name '*-beta.txt' -delete" I am posting for anybody else who is facing the same problem